# Method to select drop down values in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need a simple method to send values to "**dropID**"

values are

UAE, Bahrain,Oman... etc

drop down UI

[image]

my xpath(global)

```
//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[' + **dropID** + ']/a
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="header__countries-menu--desktop mi-js-countries-menu-desktop" style="display: block;">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=ae&amp;url=/Sponsored">UAE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=bh&amp;url=/Sponsored">Bahrain</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=om&amp;url=/Sponsored">Oman</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=qa&amp;url=/Sponsored">Qatar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=kw&amp;url=/Sponsored">Kuwait</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=eg&amp;url=/Sponsored">Egypt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header__country-selector--desktop__country">
                      <a href="/change-country?to=jo&amp;url=/Sponsored">Jordan</a>
```

I'am so new to Selenium and looking for a help

Comment: Please add the html of the dropdown on which you want to do click operation

Comment: Kindly check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

(1) Do not use absolute paths , it's bad practice. Please see below some of dynamic xpath examples:

Lets say you have this under your **CountryPage** class

WebElement countryEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='header__countries-menu--desktop mi-js-countries-menu-desktop']//*[contains(text(),'"+dynamicText+"')]") ;

or

WebElement countryEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='header__country-selector--desktop__country']//*[contains(text(),'"+dynamicText+"')]") ;

(2) You need to click on drop down in order to click any country:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("dropDown of your country ")).click();
```

(3) send your dynamic DropID to select country:

```
public static void selectFromDropdown(WebDriver driver, WebElement element)
{
    driver.findElement(element).click();
}
```

(4) call your method:

```
selectFromDropdown(driver,CountryPage(driver,"UAE"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that i have tried

```
    public void portfolioRenewalSearch(String portfolioId) throws Exception {

             By xpath2 = By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[" + portfolioId + "]/a");

           //MY ACTION IS HERE

            return;
}
```

then i called from my test cases